# VMWare Player keeps ignoring boot DVD on boot

Tags: centos, vmware-player

I have a restored clone Centos VM that needs to have it's initrd remade to boot properly. To do this I need to boot from the centos DVD. It has worked in the past but now will not. I have set the VM to look at my physical harddrive and also at an ISO and it ignores it every time then runs it's (failed boot sequence).

[image]
**How can I get the VM to boot from the DVD as it should.**?

Answer (score 0):

try to get to BIOS setup right after the boot (there is the `"go to BIOS setup screen during next boot"` checkbox somewhere in `Options` tab there) and check the boot order sequence. The CD/DVD drive is not usually the first one...

Comment: can't see that option anywhere

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lmHAW.jpg

Answer (score 0):

How to get to BIOS to change boot sequence order:

1. Open .vmx file where your VM is stored locally
2. Add this line to the end :

   bios.forceSetupOnce = "TRUE"
3. Save file and start VM.